# Turn object type into Array in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

How can I turn the following type into an Array with key/value pairs?

```js
type MyObject = {
  foo: 'bar'
  baz: 'qux'
}
```

The type I want:

```js
type MyKeyValuePair = ['foo', 'bar'] | ['baz', 'qux']
```

I've tried various combinations of keyof etc. But it never ends up as a union type, where they first param in the array, matches up with a specific value.

Comment: Map over the object and then extract the values: https://tsplay.dev/WKrbpm

Comment: Thanks. I see that I completely misunderstood how the `in` keyword works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use powerful features of Typesript - employing mapped types and conditional types. Here are steps:

1. Use a helper type to convert individual keys into tuples:

   `type ToTuple<T, K extends keyof T> = [K, T[K]];`
2. Use a mapped type to apply this helper type to each key in your object type:

```
type TupleMap<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: ToTuple<T, K>;
}[keyof T];
```

3. Now you can apply `TupleMap` to your `MyObject` type to get the desired result:

```
type MyObject = {
  foo: 'bar';
  baz: 'qux';
}

type MyKeyValuePair = TupleMap<MyObject>;  // ['foo', 'bar'] | ['baz', 'qux']
```

Good luck!